# How use mixing or subclass a vuex store?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, subclass, mixins, vuex

I have several CRUD screens that I could easily reuse in their logic.

I have for example:

```
ListScreen
|_ CustomerListScreen
|_ ProductListScreen
```

However i don't see how I can have a store per screen. Look like I need a huge global store with all there.

I wish:

```
const baseStore = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    searching:false,
    data: [],
    listUrl: '/sample'
  },
  actions:{
    search(context, term){
      console.log('SEARCH: ', term);

      context.commit('searching', true);
      context.commit('clear');
      context.searching = true;

      GET(this.listUrl)
      .then(res=>res.json())
      .then(res => {
        console.log('RESULT: ', res);

        context.commit('list', res);
        context.commit('searching', false);
      });
    }
  }
})

const customerStore = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    listUrl: '/customer'
  }
})

const productStore = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    listUrl: '/product'
  }
})
```

[Modules not work here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html), because I need to know in each screen to which module I'm talking, not making this better than a huge global object.

Comment: I already put that modules not work.

Comment: Could you explain deeper the problem, why can not use the modules?

Comment: Because modules are requiered to be references: store.state.a, store.state.b. I need to be transparent: store.state as expected when subclass.